# Process chunked response with angularjs $http

Tags: http, angularjs, chunked

I discoverd recently chunked response.
I agree that most of the time we want to work on a full response.
But what if I want to work on a chunked response.

How would i do this with the $http service??

Comment: You'll likely need to create your own service with $httpInterceptor. Do you have a sample of the chunked responses?

Comment: typically it will be json object separated by \n
Do you have exemple of such use of $httpInterceptor ?

Comment: Excuse me, I misspoke, not necessarily a service, but something that did the magic of putting the multiple responses together. ... but it sounds like you have *one* response that has many JSON parts in it?

Comment: Exactly. My idea is to use the each json object as soon as they are recieved. I ad this idea, because the list of object is long to produce, and to retrieve.

Comment: Why not put each chuck into a master JSON object, using it like a dictionary?  { 'part1': {}, 'part2': {} } ... then you could just write a service or something that got that for you and split it into it's appropriate pieces.

Comment: Sorry i wasn't clear, the chunks are slow to produce on the server side. Each json object is stored in s separate db row. And retreiving each one could take long depending on the number of record. So i want to send each record as soon as it's retreived from  the db.

Comment: Sounds like a job for multiple asynchronous requests. Must it be done in one request? Wouldn't it kill scalability to block on your webserver while one mega response was being piped out?

Comment: Your're right, this would be more scalable in a general case. But with the usage of this app, i will be the only one to use this app. So it's more an exercice than anything else.
The way i think about this woul be something like https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way to do something that looks correct to me
http://www.igvita.com/2011/08/26/server-sent-event-notifications-with-html5/

Of course there is also the websocket api, but it seams heavy for my uses

Another possibility would be the write another http service which would give control over the http response

Comment: EventSource currently isn't supported in IE.

Comment: thanks for the notice, i'l continue to search for an alternative

Answer (score 4):

You can define a function with the angularjs promise $q wrapping the XMLHttpRequest.

```
var chunkedRequestWithPromise = function () {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  xhr.open("GET", 'https://yoururl.com/chunked', true)
  xhr.onprogress = function () {
    deferred.notify(xhr.responseText);
  }
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function (oEvent) {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            deferred.resolve('success');
        } else {
            deferred.reject(xhr.statusText);
        }
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
  return deferred.promise;
};
```

and use it:

```
chunkedRequestWithPromise().then(successFn,errorFn,notifyFn);
```