# Handle chunked response from api in anjular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an api which is returning chunked response.I want to consume that api in angularjs and create a datatable from the response data so that as soon as a chunked response come i will populate the datatable and dont have to wait for full response.Is their any service or directive i can use or any other way to do it.

Comment: How about this http://oboejs.com/why ?

Comment: couldn't do it with oboejs had to fall back to xhr.If anyone has any example with oboe with chunk data please share.

Comment: Perhaps this is helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169617/process-chunked-response-with-angularjs-http/43851318#43851318